# BeanUtils: how to set value to field in parent class?

Tags: java, parent, apache-commons-beanutils

i have next classes:

```
public class A {
    private int i;
    public void setI(int i){...}
}

public class B extends A {
    private int c;
    public void setC(int c){...}
}
```

and when i try to use setProperty:

```
B b = new B();
PropertyUtils.setProperty(b, "i", 1);
```

i get next error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'i' has no setter method in class 'class org.test.B'
```

but if i try to assign value to field in class B :

```
B b = new B();
PropertyUtils.setProperty(b, "c", 1);
```

all is ok. 
So i get error only when i try to assign values to field declared in parent class.
Anyone could help? Is it possible to do what i try to do with BeanUtils?

Comment: Already tried and it works fine. Which version do you use?

Comment: java 1.7, commons-beanutils 1.9.1

Comment: Works fine... Do you have the setter? See http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtilsBean.java#2138

Comment: @PaulVargas yeap, and it is public and described in parent class

Comment: Use the file `commons-logging.properties` with a line `org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog` and the file `simplelog.properties` with the line `org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.defaultlog=all` in order to see the process for search the setter in the console log. Both file in the classpath (default package).

Comment: the problem was in result of writeable method. Beans looking for setter with void result, but my setter was with object as result.     public Object setValue(Object value){ this.value = value; return this; }     and that is why writableMethod was always null. changed result of setter method to void and everything works good. thank you all.